# "A generic error occured in GDI+" when I try to save a screen in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a rookie in C#, I try to make a screen but I can't save it where I want.
Here my code:

```
Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
pictureBox1.Image = img;
img.Save("C:\\myimage.jpeg");
```

Comment: The issue could be that the img object is in use... Is there anything else that the error message says? Does it just say a generic error?

Comment: Yes it just say me a generic error.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? A simple Windows Forms application or something more complicated, like a Windows Service?

Comment: It's a simple Windows forms which take a screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs usually when you don't have write permissions where you're trying to save the file.
This error is kind of generic, but this is one of the most frequent causes.

Check the permissions, or try to save the file somewhere else.

**UPDATE:** I noted you're using the same image in `pictureBox1`. I had no problem doing so, but you can try to use different objects to avoid concurrency and locking issues. Try this code:

```
Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
pictureBox1.Image = img;

var img2 = new Bitmap(img);
img2.Save("C:\\myimage.jpeg");
```

Comment: I tried to save it somewhere else but it doesn't work. With visual studio 2010 it save me the picture in my Dropbox ( I don't know why...) and with the 2012 it doesn't save.

Comment: I have another theory. I updated the answer to show you the code.

Comment: I tried your code, now I have "NullReferenceException was unhandled" at the line where it saves.

Comment: @Gedaym Unless the app is running as an administrator any writes to `C:\Anything.jpeg` will fail if you are on Windows Vista or newer. You said you tried elsewhere but did not say where, try saving somewhere other than the root of `C:` and see if that works.

Comment: @Gedaym, sorry for the NullReferenceException. I mistyped a variable name. I edited again to correct it.

Comment: @Gedaym, have you tried to run the application as administrator?